# Getting Name of Worksheet C++/CLI

Tags: excel, c++-cli, office-interop, msdn

How do I get the name of a worksheet in an Excel workbook using C++/cli?

I understand when you use C# you can do this:

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
string strWorksheetName = worksheet.Name;
```

Although I don't know how to do the:

```
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
```

in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would translate to the following C++/CLI:

```
Excel::Worksheet^ worksheet = dynamic_cast<Excel::Worksheet^>(sheets->get_Item(1));
String^ strWorksheetName = worksheet->Name;
```